# Cordova/Phonegap where to put Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm learning to use Cordova/Phonegap to make a web-based mobile application and am having trouble with figuring out where to place my javascript code. When you make a sample app you get a template, but I have no clue where to start off putting my own code. For example, say I want to put a simple line:

```
document.getElementById("someText").innerHTML = "Sample";
```

I wouldn't know where to place this. Here is the sample JS code they give:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Can anyone with some experience help out a noob please?

Comment: Before you start to code, READ THE DOCS, everything is explained there: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/index.html You have to start coding in the receivedEvent function.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: This is my first hybrid app, I've made an iphone game using swift before though. I'm on a mac using CLI, trying to make an ios platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you created the cordova project, in www directory all your stuff have to be placed. In www directory app.js is the script file, where you write your script as shown in your question. Link `js/app.js` in your `index.html` page and clear code in

```
   receivedEvent: function(id) {
      // Code
   }
```

and put your script in

```
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
    // Your code
  }


  app.initialize();

 // Your functions
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Your jQuery functions
 });
```

Comment: Hey one more question if you're not busy, if I want to add a line of jquery after I've imported the jquery library like this:         `$(document).click(function(){
            $("#someText").text('Waddup');
        });` Do you know where I'd put it? Or where I would add another function for that matter? Thanks!

Comment: You can put all your code in `recievedEvent:`. The difference between `receivedEvent` and linking direct script file is, the code in `receivedEvent` will be executed in an order like, it first loads the www directory files and then it will load the script files of non-manually installed cordova plugins. If you want to use `jQuery(document).ready()` You can write that below the `app.initialize();`

Comment: See as I modified the answer